# How to dynamically click a checkbox using angular directive controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

Here is my html

```
  <li 
    ng-repeat="myElement in myList">

    <input 
      type="checkbox" value="myElement"
      ng-model="checkState"
      ng-click="myDirective.updateSelectedElement(myElement, checkState)"/>
    <div>
      {{myElement.name}}
    </div>
  </li>
```

I have a `$broadcast` event such that

```
        $scope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
            // Change the checkbox state for the checkbox that have the same name in data
        })
```

The question is since my checkbox are all isolated scopes, I don't have access to it, is there a way to access the checkbox that have specific `myElement.name`

Thanks

Comment: are you saying that you are broadcasting from controller A? and you expect to respond to the broadcast on controller B (where your checkboxes live) ?

Comment: @Ji_in_coding yes, I am doing this to pre fill checkbox from an API call

Answer (score 0):

Doing it through the rootscope will solve your problem

```
app.controller("ControllerA", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope){
    $rootScope.$broadcast("myEvent");
}]);


app.controller("ControllerB", ["$scope", "$rootScope", function($scope, $rootScope){

    $rootScope.$on('myEvent', function(event, data){
        $scope.checkState = true;
    })
}]);
```

Comment: `checkState` is isolated to each checkbox. I don't have access to it

Comment: @testing are you not able to access it from myList[i].prop ? You might need to provide more code to let me have a better understanding of your problem

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example of code that I wrote to show how checkboxes could be programmatically checked and unchecked from outside of the directive using events. I use buttons in this example, but you could call the methods from inside the controller as well.

[Example in Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/pFfD5pFutai2grg7G3kg)

Also, as a best practice, if you are dispatching an event from rootScope and listening for it on rootScope as well, use $emit instead of $broadcast so that the event starts and ends at rootScope and is not broadcast down the scope chain.

Angular Code

```
angular.module('app', [

]).controller('MainController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $rootScope) {
    $scope.list = [{label: 'Camaro'}, {label: 'Chevette'}, {label: 'Corvette'}];
    $scope.checkItem = function (label, status) {
      $rootScope.$emit('checkItemEvent', {label: label, check: status});
    }; 
  }])

  .directive('checkboxDirective', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
      restrict: 'AE',
      template: '<input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checkState"/><span>{{item.label}}</span>',
      require: 'ngModel',
      scope: {
        item: '=ngModel'
      },
      link: function ($scope) {
        console.log('$scope.item', $scope.item);
        $rootScope.$on('checkItemEvent', function (event, data) {
          console.log('data', data);
          if (data.label === $scope.item.label) {
            $scope.item.checkState = data.check;
          }
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainController">
    <h1>Checkbox demo</h1>
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in list">
        <checkbox-directive ng-model="item"></checkbox-directive>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div>
      <button ng-click="checkItem('Corvette', true)">Check Corvette</button>
      <button ng-click="checkItem('Corvette', false)">Uncheck Corvette</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```